# OpenCV HighGui fullscreen under linux

Tags: c++, ubuntu, opencv

I'm trying to make a simple fullscreen app to display the output of a camera using Open CV. I've got most of the code developed already, I'm just trying to make it fullscreen the window appropriately. I've pared back to the most basic of basic code as follows (taken from the OpenCV website):

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

int main ( int argc, char **argv )
{
  cvNamedWindow( "My Window", 1 );
  IplImage *img = cvCreateImage( cvSize( 1920, 1200 ), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1 );
  CvFont font;
  double hScale = 1.0;
  double vScale = 1.0;
  int lineWidth = 3;
  cvInitFont( &font, CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX | CV_FONT_ITALIC, hScale, vScale, 0, lineWidth );
  cvPutText( img, "Hello World!", cvPoint( 200, 400 ), &font, cvScalar( 255, 255, 0 ) );
  cvSetWindowProperty( "My Window", CV_WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, CV_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN );
  cvShowImage( "My Window", img );
  cvWaitKey();
  return 0;
}
```

When I run this, the window gets created at the 1920x1200 resolution requested, but it's not fullscreened, it's just a normal HighGUI window. I could swear I had this working earlier, but have since trashed and re-installed Ubuntu, and have a feeling I may have forgotten something along the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
cvNamedWindow( "My Window", 1 );
```

to

```
cvNamedWindow( "My Window", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL );
```

Check the [flags for cvNamedWindow](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/user_interface.html#namedwindow).

Comment: Cheers Bob,

I've been staring at library and link issues for the past 3 days now, I think the part of my brain devoted to basic debugging has been swallowed by the wave of soul-destroying link errors.