# how to display image on full screen mode

Tags: python, image, screen, fullscreen

I'm trying display any image in full screen mode with `os.startfile('image.png')`

How I can open my picture on full screen mode with default visualizator?
Through PYTHON .

example code:

```
import os
os.startfile('image.png')
```

EDIT: can't I do it without using opencv?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just execute the command with the image name.

```
import os
os.system('image.png')
```

It will open the image in default image viewer.

Related [option for full screen using opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17696061/how-to-display-a-full-screen-images-with-python2-7-and-opencv2-4)

Comment: can't I do it without using opencv?